# Tumblr disabled custom domain for using CloudFlare

Tags: domains, dns, cdn, cloudflare, tumblr

I have a Tumblr blog which uses a custom domain. Yesterday I tried to add CloudFlare to it which was a terrible mistake. Apparently Tumblr does not support Cloudflare and will therefore [disable domains using it](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168566-How-do-I-add-a-Tumblr-custom-domain-)

I have now removed CloudFlare but the domain still won't work, saying that 'This domain’s A-record is not pointing to Tumblr.' It is of course pointing to Tumblr and I think they are just blocking because I used CloudFlare.

Reading the [answers from Quora](http://www.quora.com/Why-has-tumblr-said-that-CloudFlare-is-not-compatible-with-tumblr-Is-CloudFlare-causing-technical-problems-for-tumblr-or-are-there-other-reasons), it seems like it should fix itself once you turn off the CDN.
Am I missing something because I can't seem to get my domain working again?

Comment: Just to note -- this has been an issue for roughly 3 years now. Please certainly let Tumblr know if you'd like them to consider changing their policy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can actually manage the DNS for the record pointing to Tumblr. You can't, however, have our proxy (orange cloud) turned on for the record & it should be grey (direct).

Comment: Just to note -- this has been an issue for roughly 3 years now. Please certainly let Tumblr know if you'd like them to consider changing their policy.

Answer (score 2):

You are not missing something but it might take a little while to pop back into life and you might need to turn "use custom domain" back on in your tumblr settings. I tried to do this myself for my own tumblr site and failed too. If you think think about it, it is obvious that tumblr would ban Cloudflare, as it would take the content of the tumblr pages completely out of their control.

For example, I wanted to to use [Cloudflare's apps](https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/) to add some light advertising on my pages since they are pretty popular. That would have taken a few clicks with Cloudflare apps rewriting my tumblr pages on the fly as they pass through the Cloudflare CDN. But from that list of apps I link to, you can see that it would be very easy to make a tumblr site that was absolutely encrusted in several types of advertising, and so I would guess that for that reason, tumblr will never allow it.